# How do I install a platform into my android device using Windows not Eclipse?

Tags: android

I know its easy to do this with Eclipse but i dont have that. can someone please tell me how to do this step by step on Windows??

Comment: why u want to do that..? anyways if u want to then go to android developer manual. u will find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three points.

1. This should really have been an edit
   to your original post instead of a
   whole new question.
2. Eclipse is free,
   runs on Windows and makes it easy to
   get started with Android
   development, get it!
3. You don't
   install the AVD's on to a device. 
   You use the AVD's with the emulator
   so that it can emulate different
   hardware configurations.  The device
   you have has a certain configuration
   and the only ways to change that are
   to get a valid update from the
   provider or to root the device and
   flash a new firmware.